# Determining if a solution will boil

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, temperature

A piston compresses a solution of 40% $HNO_3$ in $H_2O$. If the piston breaks and the pressure is reduced from 12.0 atm to 1.0 atm:

a) If the temperature of the solution is 110 degrees C, will the solution boil?
b) If another vessel contains 35% $HNO_3$ in $H_2O$ under the same circumstances, will the solution boil?

I'm not sure how to tell if a solution will boil. I know that I can use a table to find the partial pressure (p*) of $HNO_3$ and $H_2O$ at the designated temperature, but what information does the pressure give me?

Comment: I don't see what you mean by _"A piston compresses a solution"_ because liquids are _virtually incompressible_. Do you mean _pressurizes_?. To answer your question: a solution boils if its partial pressure is greater than the atmospheric pressure.

Comment: The solution is heated, so presumably there is some vapor. In this case would the atmospheric pressure just be 1.0 atm? Does the drop from 12 to 1 make a difference towards answering the problem?

Comment: Boiling of a mixture is a complex process. In addition to pressure and temperature, boiling now depends also on the composition in liquid as well as vapor phase. This is of course true if the components are miscible (not true otherwise). For a single component liquid-gas system, boiling occurs when the pressure of vapor on top of liquid is less than the saturation vapor pressure of the gas-liquid system at the given temperature. In this case, some liquid boils to form gas thereby increasing the pressure of vapor on top which eventually goes to the saturation vapor pressure.

Answer (score 1):

A solution boils if its vapour pressure is greater than the atmospheric pressure (or rather, the pressure pressing down on the solution)

So in the first case, you find the vapour pressure of the solution at 110 degrees C. It will most definitely be less than 12atm, in which case the solution will not boil. When you release the 12 atm pressure, see if the vapour pressure is greater than 1atm. if yes, it will boil, if not, no boiling

Comment: So the partial pressure will not change in either circumstance (when the pressure of the piston changes)?

Comment: No. The partial pressure of the liquid stays the same. The partial pressure is just the vapour exerted due to the equilibrium of the liquid-vapour phase

Comment: So am I only accounting for the partial pressure of HNO3, or the addition of HNO3 and H2O?

Comment: @JohnJaycum, there is a vapour pressure and a vapour-liquid equilibrium at all temperatures above absolute zero.

Comment: @JohnJaycum, correction: I was saying partial pressure. I meant vapour pressure. You should account for the total vapour pressure, see this for details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapor_pressure#Liquid_mixtures

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret this. If I have ${p^*}_{HNO3}$ and ${p^*}_{H2O}$, do I add them together to determine if the solution will boil?

Comment: You use the molar fraction. Suppose you have $N_a$ moles of acid and $N_w$ moles of water. The molar fractions are $X_a = \frac{N_a}{N_a+N_w}$ and $X_w = \frac{N_w}{N_a + N_w}$. The net vapour pressure $p^*_{net} = p^*_w \times X_w + p^*_a \times X_a$

Comment: Oh, OK. So I would instead be interpreting ${p^*}_{HNO3}*0.35 + {p^*}_{H2O}*0.65$ in the context of the problem?

Comment: @JohnJaycum Nope. Molar ratio, not volume ratio. $N_a = 0.35 \times molar wt. of acid$ and so on